# Is it right to post a "reference" question?

Tags: discussion, questions

There is a [question on Stack Overflow which agglomerate a list of questions related to PHP symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php). This is a good way to discover some rarely symbols, even for someone who has no problem.

Can I add a question on UX in order to gather interesting questions or answers about website forms?

Here are examples of some questions or answers that I found to be inspiring:

Forms layout:

- [Why might right aligned field labels be better?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8873/why-might-right-aligned-field-labels-be-better)
- [Are users confused by the file upload element?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51690/are-users-confused-by-the-file-upload-element/52297#52297)
- [Update vs Modify vs Change - Create vs Add - Delete vs Remove](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/43174/update-vs-modify-vs-change-create-vs-add-delete-vs-remove)

Localization:

- [Common website phrases in multiple languages?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52390/common-website-phrases-in-multiple-languages)

Tables:

- [Column header alignment](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12881/column-header-alignment)

While writing this question, I realize that these questions are not strictly focused on forms, but you can just see these as examples.

One problem will arise: what can be considered a *reference* answer and not just a useful but subjective answer? Maybe the *reference* word is too strict. Providing a list of answers without pretending they are *reference* may still be useful. It may be called *Summary of interesting questions and answers about web forms*.

Comment: Isn't that what the tag wiki system is for?

Comment: Yes, I completely forgot about tags when asking this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally not. Stack Overflow and, very rarely, a few other sites will do this, but it's not really the point of questions/answers, it's more of a weird hack. In this case, it's been done because there are lots of extremely common issues (as in several practically identical questions a day). UX doesn't get nearly that sort of repetition yet and doesn't have remotely as many questions per tag.

Tags are really what should be used for "reference", and ideally the Tag Wiki could be used (however it seems no one uses them so it might be a pointless effort). I would say for now we don't really need "reference questions" of that format, and the best way to find relevant questions about forms is just to search or checkout the [forms](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms) page.

If there comes a time we're practically stumbling over ourselves to find the "proper" duplicate for extremely common (daily) questions repeated over and over again, we might need something of a reference question. For now it seems like it would be a bit unnecessary (and better suited for a tag wiki perhaps).

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks!